# A button handling same event for 2 different buttons depending upon which one is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, events, buttonclick

I an developing this UI, that has 3 buttons.

1. delete
2. referesh process
3. save

user selects the row from the data grid and clicks on any of the 2 buttons, i.e delete or refresh process, but until and unless user presses the save button the changes are not saved into data base.

i was thinking to have same save button for delete and refresh process, depending upon which button user has clicked, UI will call stored procs.

The application is on C#, WPF.

Please give me some idea on how can i handle this or some other suggestion.

Comment: Encapsulate the save logic into a method and call it in the clicks as you require !

Comment: What if the user clicks Delete then Refresh then Save for the same row? :)

Comment: if user clicks delete first and then refresh process. are deleted rows added to gridview when refresh button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the selected row with you. You could have `global boolean variable isDeleteClicked`. When user clicks the delete button, in its event handler, you could set `isDeleteClicked = true;` When user clicks refresh process button, in that button event handler, you could do `isDeleteClicked = false;` When save button is clicked, in its event handler you could do

```
if(isDeleteClicked)
{
//call SP for delete work
}
else
{
//call SP for refresh work
}
```

Or another option could be to create an enumeration wtih three values for example.

```
public enum OperationSelected
    {
        DeleteClicked,
        RefreshProcessClicked,
        NoneClicked
    }
```

Create a global enum variable opSelected like `OperationSelected opSelected = OperationSelected.NoneClicked;` On delete button event handler do

```
opSelected = OperationSelected.DeleteClicked;
```

On refresh process button event handler do

```
opSelected = OperationSelected.RefreshProcessClicked;
```

On Save button event handler do

```
    if (opSelected.ToString() == OperationSelected.DeleteClicked.ToString())
    {
    //call SP for delete work
    }
    else  if (opSelected.ToString() == OperationSelected.RefreshProcessClicked.ToString())
    {
    //call SP for refresh work
    }
```

Comment: And how will you know for which row was Delete or Refresh selected?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to just store which button was clicked and what row was selected and process this data in the Save handler.
Clicking the Delete or Refresh will overwrite the two flags (whichButton and gridRow). Based on the value of whichButton your Save handler then does the appropriate logic.

This means you can save only one change, which is what you seem to say...

If you want to be able to queue more row changes then you need to store the two flags above in a container and process the entries one by one in the Save handler. Think about what happens if the same row is added to the container for both a Refresh and a Delete...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you have as a data source for the grid. If the backend supports Unit of work (like EF or NHibernate) then you change data directly and the context will resolve changes and their order when you call Save on the context.

If you use some bound-list of objects as a data source (a View Model, highly recommended for a WPF app) then you should add a new field to the ViewModel `ChangeType = ChangeType.RefreshProcess or ChangeType.Deleted` and then on Save you process actions based on the Changed field.